# Flutter run failing on IOS emulator

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I have installed all of the tehnollogies and dependancies.
When i run `flutter run --flavor dev -t lib/main.dev.dart -d my-simulator-id-here`.

I get the following error:

```
Launching lib/main.dev.dart on iPhone 14 in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...                                                  
Xcode build done.                                            2.3s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    2023-07-18 09:43:04.693 xcodebuild[76832:784181] DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState: DVTCoreDeviceEnabledState_Disabled set via user default
    (DVTEnableCoreDevice=disabled)
    xcodebuild: error: Unable to find a destination matching the provided destination specifier:
                { id:my-simulator-id-here }

        Available destinations for the "dev" scheme:
                { platform:macOS, arch:arm64, variant:Designed for [iPad,iPhone], id:some-id }
                { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }

Xcode's output:
↳
    Writing result bundle at path:
        /var/folders/mh/jzc2_s9d72d7t4wg2rv2x_gr0000gn/T/flutter_tools.Ky2kr7/flutter_ios_build_temp_dirfIPoHT/temporary_xcresult_bundle

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
```

I tried starting the app in different ways, updating package versions, changing/reseting IOS simulator.

Comment: perhaps is your IOS simulator version is lower than your project deployments target version, try to update your IOS simulator, or increase your project deployments target version

Comment: My simulator IOS version is 16.4 and the minimum deployment for the project is 13.0. So this should not be a problem, I suppose.